# recibir imágenes de un formulario en PHP

Tags: php, html

el código es muy simple

```
<form action="scripts/cargarFormulario.php" method="post" id="formulario" class="datos" enctype="multipart/formdata">
        <input type="file" name="imagen[]" id="input-file" multiple>
        <input type="submit" name="guardarDatos" value="Publicar">
</form>
```

PHP: archivo cargarFormulario.php

```
if (isset($_FILES['imagen'])){
    echo "archivo cargado";
}else{
    echo "no hay archivos";
}
```

he visto infinidad de tutoriales y en todos esto funciona correctamente pero en mi caso esto siempre devuelve "no hay archivos" (ósea entra en el else)
cabe destacar que en ese mismo formulario tengo otros input de tipo texto, number, etc que si son recibidos correctamente por php. el problema es con el de tipo file

Comment: ¿donde tienes el submit?

Comment: Coloca un `var_dump($_FILES);` al inicio de tu script y dinos que muestra. Explica además de qué modo estarías enviando el formulario al servidor ¿?

Comment: te falta un punto y coma al final del `"no hay archivos"`, sino da error de PHP

Comment: ¿Y porque lo pones `hidden`?  ¿asi como vas a subir nada si no puedes seleccionar ningun archivo?

Comment: Otra cosa muy extraña es que tu input tiene el atributo `hidden`, por lo que, en principio, el mismo no sería visible. ¿Lo haces visible luego de algún modo por código Javascript u otro? Ten en cuenta que el hecho de poner un input de tipo `file` en un formulario no te va a enviar un archivo, ese input debe usarse para elegir un archivo o varios archivos en el cliente, los cuales se enviarán cuando envíes el formulario.

Comment: visto, aparte de todo lo que te hemos ya dicho, que seguramente es porque has **minimizado** el código a mostrarnos, el problema lo tienes en el `enctype="multipart/formdata"` que tiene que ser con guion entre **form** y **data** y ya esta, todo arreglado. O sea, ponlo así: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  (he conseguido reproducir tu error localmente y eso lo arregla todo). O sea, es un error tipográfico.

Comment: modifique el código publicado para no seguir confundiendo (perdón por eso) el problema era tal como dijo @masterguru el enctype="multipart/formdata" estaba mal escrito deberia de ser enctype="multipart/form-data" (eso soluciono todo) Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que no te has leido los comentarios, asi que publico aqui una respuesta, aunque creo que solo es un error tipografico y en ese caso la pregunta deberia ser borrada:

Debes cambiar este atributo en el **form**

```
enctype="multipart/formdata"
```

por este otro:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

y empezará a funcionarte mejor.